# How to disable scientific notation in QCompleter?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside, qcompleter

I have a table with some records that are keyed using a very large number as the primary key. I have code similar to the following which uses `QCompleter` to autocomplete lookups in this table. It works, but the displayed completions are formatted using the scientific notation (1234567 => 1.23e6). I'd like to have my completions displayed as-is. In my opinion, I'd either need to cast the response from the query as a string (can't figure out how to do this) or set a property on the `QLineEdit` to disable scientific notation formatting (can't figure this out either). Any ideas?

```
class MyDialog(BaseObject, QtGui.QDialog):
     def __init__(self, ... db=None):
         super(MyDialog, self).__init__(parent, logger)
        self.qsql_db = db
        self.init_ui()

    def mk_model(self, completer, pFilterModel, table_name, filter_=None):
        model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel()
        model.setTable(table_name)
        if filter_:
            model.setFilter(filter_)
        model.select()
        pFilterModel.setSourceModel(model)
        completer.setModel(pFilterModel)
        return model

    def setModelColumn(self, completer, pFilterModel, column):
        completer.setCompletionColumn(column)
        pFilterModel.setFilterKeyColumn(column)

    def mk_receipt_id_grid(self):
        font = self.mk_font()
        label_receipt_id = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        label_receipt_id.setText("Order ID")
        label_receipt_id.setFont(font)
        self.text_edit_receipt_id = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.text_edit_receipt_id.setFont(font)
        label_receipt_id.setBuddy(self.text_edit_receipt_id)
        self.formGridLayout.addWidget(label_receipt_id, 0, 0)
        self.formGridLayout.addWidget(self.text_edit_receipt_id, 0, 1)
        self.connect(self.text_edit_receipt_id,
                 QtCore.SIGNAL("editingFinished()"),
                 self.get_order_details)

        completer = QtGui.QCompleter(self)
        completer.setCompletionMode(QtGui.QCompleter.UnfilteredPopupCompletion)
        pFilterModel = QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
        pFilterModel.setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        completer.setPopup(completer.popup())
        self.text_edit_receipt_id.setCompleter(completer)
        model = self.mk_model(completer, pFilterModel, "orders", "created_at > date_trunc('day', now())")
        self.setModelColumn(completer, pFilterModel, model.fieldIndex("receipt_id"))
        self.text_edit_receipt_id.textEdited.connect(pFilterModel.setFilterFixedString)
```

Screenshot of the issue: [image: Screenshot of the issue:]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this would be to set an item-delegate on the completer's view. The [QStyledItemDelegate](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html) class has a [`displayText`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#displayText) method that can be overridden, which makes implementing this quite easy.

Here is a simple demo:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class ItemDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def displayText(self, data, locale):
        if isinstance(data, (int, float)):
            data = '%d' % data
        return super(ItemDelegate, self).displayText(data, locale)

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        edit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(edit)
        completer = QtGui.QCompleter(self)
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        for value in (
            17596767040000.0, 47993723466378568.0,
            1219073478568475.0, 43726487587345.0,
            29928757235623.0, 2245634345639486934.0,
            ):
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem()
            item.setData(value, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
            model.appendRow([item])
        completer.setModel(model)
        completer.popup().setItemDelegate(ItemDelegate(self))
        edit.setCompleter(completer)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 300, 50)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: hmm I thought as simple as casting `double` to `real` or  ?

Comment: Had to declare a variable holding  completer.popup(). I think it was getting GC'd

Comment: @Lmwangi. That sounds like a pyside bug - what version are you using? (Works fine for me using pyside-1.2.4 on linux).

Comment: @ekhumoro I am using PyQt, to be specific, whatever is shipping on debian jessie which is 4.11.2+dfsg-1. Thanks for the help btw.